# Inverse probability density function

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

What do I have to use to figure out the inverse probability density function for normal distribution? I'm using scipy to find out normal distribution probability density function:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm.pdf(1000, loc=1040, scale=210)
0.0018655737107410499
```

How can I figure out that 0.0018 probability corresponds to 1000 in the given normal distribution?

Comment: `0.0018` is not a probability, it is a probability density. What do you want to use the inverse pdf for? I don't think I have ever seen it used anywhere in statistics. The more common thing is searching for the inverse of the cumulative density function, the cdf, which does return probabilities. You can get the inverse cdf as `norm.ppf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be no 1:1 mapping from probability density to quantile.

[image]

Because the PDF of the normal distribution is quadratic, there can be either 2, 1 or zero quantiles that have a particular probability density.

### Update

It's actually not that hard to find the roots analytically. The PDF of a normal distribution is given by:

[image]

With a bit of rearrangement we get:

```
(x - mu)**2 = -2 * sigma**2 * log( pd * sigma * sqrt(2 * pi))
```

If the discriminant on the RHS is < 0, there are no real roots. If it equals zero, there is a single root (where *x* = *mu*), and where it is > 0 there are two roots.

To put it all together into a function:

```
import numpy as np

def get_quantiles(pd, mu, sigma):

    discrim = -2 * sigma**2 * np.log(pd * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))

    # no real roots
    if discrim < 0:
        return None

    # one root, where x == mu
    elif discrim == 0:
        return mu

    # two roots
    else:
        return mu - np.sqrt(discrim), mu + np.sqrt(discrim)
```

This gives the desired quantile(s), to within rounding error:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
pd = norm.pdf(1000, loc=1040, scale=210)
print get_quantiles(pd, 1040, 210)
# (1000.0000000000001, 1079.9999999999998)
```

Comment: Why is it impossible to find all the quantiles?

Comment: Sure, you could solve for x in [the equation for the PDF here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/6/4/564914214ead956aceccd30b78d2f6ee.png), as long as there is at least one real root for your chosen density value. I understood from your phrasing of the question that you wanted a 1:1 mapping from probability density -> quantile, which would be impossible.

Comment: These two answers are really great. This one solves this problem analytically, and other with optimize.fsolve solves the problem numerically. But I decided to mark this one "accepted", because analitical solutions are more efficient for figuring out roots of given precision.

Answer (score 4):

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.optimize as optimize
norm = stats.norm(loc=1040, scale=210)
y = norm.pdf(1000)
print(y)
# 0.00186557371074

print(optimize.fsolve(lambda x:norm.pdf(x)-y, norm.mean()-norm.std()))
# [ 1000.]
print(optimize.fsolve(lambda x:norm.pdf(x)-y, norm.mean()+norm.std()))
# [ 1080.]
```

There exist distributions which attain any value an infinite number of times. (For example, the simple function with value 1 on an infinite sequence of intervals with lengths 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc. attains the value 1 an infinite number of times. And it is a distribution since 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 1)

So the use of `fsolve` above is not guaranteed to find all values of `x` where `pdf(x)` equals a certain value, but it may help you find *some* root.